# Order a database created with Pydblite for Items created with Scrapy

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, scrapy

I have built a pipeline that inserts the Items created with Scrapy in a database ( with id ) . But these are placed in a disorderly manner.

After all the various elements have been incorporated into the database, i would try to sort through ID ( in this case uid ).

This is my Pipeline:

```
class DBPipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.db = Base('test.pdl')
    self.db.create('uid', 'type', 'author', 'title', mode="open")

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.db.insert(
                   uid=item['uid'],
                   type=item['type'],
                   author=item['author'],
                   title=item['title'],
                   )
    self.db.commit()
    return item
```

**Problem**
The items created during the Web scraping are so many, so Scrapy not always places them in an orderly fashion .